# How to debug Pages.app on Mac OS?

Tags: macos, shell, lldb

I'm trying to find a way to debug Pages.app in Mac using lldb.
So I need to start the Pages from a command line like this: `open Pages xxx.pages` .

But the command `open` is not useful here because
`lldb open Pages` is just debug the binary `open` but not Pages.

I've tried using
`/Applications/Pages.app/Contents/MacOS/Pages myDoc.pages`, but it can't open the doc for unknown reason.

I guess there must be some way to start app from command line without `open`, anyone has some solutions?

Comment: Do you need to specifically debug Pages being **launched** with a document? You could run `lldb /Applications/Pages.app/Contents/MacOS/Pages` with no document and then, once it's running, open the document (either using `open` or the Finder or whatever). Also, debugging an app without source is going to be difficult.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. But in my case the document is not always the same. So I'm trying to do my work in lldb python script like this:  `>run xxx.pages`, and then the Pages will tell me unable to open file for unknow reason.

Comment: Oh I've think it over, seems that using `open` is a good solution. I'll try it, thanks again.